# Simple html form.. action field not being executed

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets, action

I have a simple html form (first name and last name) once I hit submit it should give me a simple response from my java servlet that says "Hello plus first name plus last name"

I ran this using eclipse and a tomcat plugin and it works perfectly.. but when I create a war file and deploy it from tomcat.. I get the first screen.. enter first and last name.. but when I hit submit, it looks for "WelcomeScreen" nowhere in my code do i have "welcomeScreen" Below is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Please enter your name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="input" action=Hello method="get">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last
        name: <input type="text" name="lastname"> <input type="submit"
            value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it is a typo, correct it by putting quotes around `Hello`.

Comment: my mistake.. I accidentally left out what I have tried so far...I have tried to replace what I have in the action field with..."Hello" even tried to put https://www.google.com and it still didnt work.. on eclipse when I would do this.. fill the form out, submit it, it should go onto the next page/servlet or whatever you say it should go to.. works on eclipse.. but not when I deploy and run it from tomcat(terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Please enter your name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="input" action="Hello.html" method="get">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br> 
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrote correct code. There were some mistakes in html like;

```
<form name="input" action=Hello method="get"> 
<!-- You've forgotten quotes -->
<!-- And also dont forget to write ".html" or Hello controller in framework like MVC -->
<form name="input" action="Hello.html" method="get">
```

Another one

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<!-- You've forgotten /// -->
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
```

And your Hello.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var get = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
        alert(get);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for the quick help!